# Will a Winforms grid keep its datasource in memory? .Net

Tags: winforms, memory-management, datagrid, dataset

I've a grid in my winforms application and i bind a huge dataset to the grid. Will the dataset be stored in the memory by the grid after calling DataBind(). How does it operate on the data binded to the grid?

Update

I wrote the following code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=testv;Pwd=pass"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Sample", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
                {
                    ada.Fill(dt);
                    dgvMain.DataSource = dt;
                    dt.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

After assigning the datatable as the datasource i'm able to dispose it. So does it make a copy in the memory?

Thanks

NLV

Comment: Am i not clear with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a copy, it makes a reference to the original datasource object.

P.S. Making a huge dataset is not a good idea anyway. If you need to display lots of rows, make some kind of paging or filters and restrict number of rows to load and display.